# How to prevent download from being stopped if network got disconnected?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, chrome-for-android, downloading

I use WiFi on home and on CyanogenMod 12.1 so I use chrome browser latest update on it. So when I am downloading file but for some reason I have to go outside , as the moment I disconnects from network download stops. Any solution to prevent this thing?
I tried That part download thing in download folder but its not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need some kind of internet connection to download files. From what you said, the download stops when you disconnect from your network.

If you meant that the download doesn't work over mobile data, check the list of apps with restricted background data access for *Download Manager* or, of course, Chrome. If one of those apps have restricted background data, disable that option. If it still doesn't work, try a different browser and tell me whether that worked.

Comment: Nope it works on data but I usually not use any data pack(once in month) . There is no issue with restricted background data. Trying different browser now

Comment: So what exactly is the problem if it works both on WiFi and mobile data?

Comment: I don't want it to abruptly stop download instead of that it should be started where it was left.

Comment: Tell me whether I understood it correctly. You have an issue and downloads don't resume from where they stopped, right?

Comment: Yep that's the problem